# Is it possible to replace some files in android project withou actually replacing them (via .gradle/gradle.properties)

Tags: android, gradle

Android studio project
Win10 machine(if it's matter).
Specific project at specific local location.
I need to force https interception on local builds. Making and commiting fix for networksecurityconfig.xml even for dev build is not possible due to non-technical reasons.
making local modification, keep it in stash and never commit is possible but is there other way?
Is it possible to include other versions of specific files (networksecurityconfig.xml) in local builds via global gradle properties) without ANY modifications to project's source code (global gradle config modification is ok, even custom plugins for Android Studio are ok).

Comment: create a module and add the relevant folders there. We tried it and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Android can automatically replace files based on the BuildVariant and/or Build Type.
E.g. you can use a different `networksecurityconfig.xml` in your debug builds vs your release builds.

**Debug vs Release**

In your Debug folder:

```
src/main/debug/res/xml/network_security_config.xml // debug config
```

And in your Release folder:

```
src/main/release/res/xml/network_security_config.xml // release config
```

This requires no additional setup.
Alternatively, you could create a new BuildType, if you would like to make it more explicit

**Build Type**

build.gradle

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug{...}
        secure{..}
        release{...}
    }
}
```

And place the desired `network_security_config.xml` in the secure source set:

```
src/main/secure/res/xml/network_security_config.xml // secure configuration
```

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types)

Comment: Not going to work in this specific case. This require updating sources (and keeping changes in stash because it's not ok to commit such changes(reason for this is not technical) and I want to avoid this. If it was ok to modif sources for this - I would just added 'debugOverrides'  to existing file.